# UITableView per-cell selection mode while editing

Tags: iphone, uitableview, selection

In my `UITableView`, when it enters editing mode, I'd like only a select few cells to be selectable. I know the `UITableView` class has the property `allowsSelectionDuringEditing`, but this applies to the whole `UITableView`. I don't see any relevant delegate methods to set this on a per-cell basis.

The best solution I can come up with is to set `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` to `YES`. Then, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, filter out any unwanted selections if the table view is editing. Also, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, change those cells `selectionStyle` to None.

The problem with this is that going into editing mode does not reload the `UITableViewCells`, so their `selectionStyle` doesn't change until they scroll offscreen. So, in setEditing, I also have to iterate over the visible cells and set their `selectionStyle`.

This works, but I just wonder if there is a better/more elegant solution to this problem. The basic outline of my code is attached. Any suggestions greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    if (self.editing && ![self _isUtilityRow:indexPath]) return;
    // Otherwise, do the normal thing...
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    // UITableViewCell* cell = ...

    if (self.editing && ![self _isUtilityRow:indexPath])
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing)
    {
        for (UITableViewCell* cell in [self.tableView visibleCells])
        {
            if (![self _isUtilityRow:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]])
            {
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (UITableViewCell* cell in [self.tableView visibleCells])
        {
            if (![self _isUtilityRow:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]])
            {
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could reload the table when it goes into editing mode, or deselect the row as soon as it is selected rather than setting the selection style to none...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your app works, but perhaps you could try make use of the following somewhere in your DataSource definition:

```
// Individual rows can opt out of having the -editing property set for them. If not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable.

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

when going into editing mode, use the function to filter the first selection level, then on to your second selection level